# How can I create HTML/CSS responsive tile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I try to understand how CSS and responsive design works. I made a small example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4st13n/xB7tb/2/).

This is a simple tile template.

I would like to be able to show my tile on 2, 3, 4 or more columns. In this sample you just need to change the div "wrapper" class `c2, c3, c4` to modify the number of columns.

This works because my tile are floating left and these `c2, c3, c4` modify the width of my wrapper. See HTML and CSS file or go on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4st13n/xB7tb/2/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper c2"> <!-- try with c3, c4-->
    <div class="scrollable">
        <div class="webbutiles">
            <a href='?page_id=77'  class='tile TBlue iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-group'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile 1</div></div></a>
            <a href='?page_id=85'  class='tile TDarkGreen iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-comments-alt'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile 2</div></div></a>
            <a href='?page_id=89'  class='tile TDarkPurple iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-cogs'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile 3</div></div></a>
            <a href='?page_id=91'  class='tile TDarkBlue iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-table'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile 4</div></div></a>
            <a href='?page_id=93'  class='tile TDarkRed iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-heart'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile 5</div></div></a>
            <a href='?page_id=95'  class='tile TTwitterBlue iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-twitter'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile 6</div></div></a>
            <a href='?page_id=97'  class='tile TGreen iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-columns'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile 7</div></div></a>
            <a href='?page_id=87'  class='tile TOrange t2x iconmain '><div class='boxContent'><i class='icon-reorder'></i></div><div class='tilename '><div class='name'>Tile Large</div></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    /* General tile settings */
.tile{ display:block;  float:left;  background-color:#525252;  width:150px;  height:150px;  cursor:pointer;  text-decoration:none;  color:#fff;  overflow:hidden;  position:relative;  font-weight:300;  font-size:11pt;  letter-spacing:0.02em;  line-height:20px;  margin:0 10px 10px 0;  overflow:hidden}
.tile:hover{ outline:3px #3a3a3a solid}


/* Tile responsive setting. */
@media (min-width:1025px){
    .wrapper{width:1024px}
}

.wrapper{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto}
.wrapper.c2{width:400px}
.wrapper.c3{width:600px}
.wrapper.c4{width:800px}
.wrapper.c5{width:1000px}
.resimgicon {max-width:62px;height:auto;}
.tile .boxContent .resimgicon{ margin-left: 3em; margin-top: 2.7em;}
.tile{ width:157px;  height:157px}
.tile.t2x{ width:324px}
.tile.t2x .boxContent{ width:324px}

@media (max-width:640px){
    .wrapper{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto}
    .wrapper.c2{width:324px}
    .wrapper.c3{width:491px}
    .wrapper.c4{width:658px}
    .wrapper.c5{width:785px}
    .resimgicon {max-width:64px;height:auto;}
    .tile .boxContent .resimgicon{ margin-left: 2.7em; margin-top: 2.8em;}
    .tile{ width:147px;  height:147px}
    .tile.t2x{ width:304px}
    .tile.t2x .boxContent{ width:304px}
}

@media (max-width:360px){
    .wrapper{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto}
    .wrapper.c2{width:184px}
    .wrapper.c3{width:281px}
    .wrapper.c4{width:378px}
    .wrapper.c5{width:435px}
    .resimgicon {max-width:38px;height:auto;}
    .tile .boxContent .resimgicon{ margin-left: .74em; margin-top: .68em;}
    .tile{ width:77px;  height:77px}
    .tile.t2x{ width:164px}
    .tile.t2x .boxContent{ width:164px}
}
```

I don't like this CSS because I don't like to work with a fixed tile and wrapper size. This create a left and right (auto) marging. That not a problem for big sreen but it's useless on a phone or tablet screen.

What should I do tho create a tile system with column without having to a fixed wrapper width ? Is there a better way to generate this kind of tile ?

Comment: work with `%` instead of a fixed amount of `px`

Comment: If you want to be fully responsive, and cut down on some code, embrace percentage widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way.. You're kind of doing it backwards from how its done everywhere else.

Instead of modfying the width of your wrapper, you want the wrapper to be fluid in width.  meaning it can be 320px wide or 2560px wide.

Then... give a set of pre-set column widths calculated in percentages, based on a grid system.

Let's say you want a maximum of 12 columns wide.  Every set of columns then must equal a total of 12.

Then for example if you want a full width column, you would call this class "col-12" and give it `width: 100%;`

Then if you wanted two columns, both equal in width for example with a 3.8% marging between them.  Then you would calculate 100% - 3.8% = 96.2% then 96.2% / 2 = 48.1%.  Make a class called col-6 that has `width: 48.1%` and `margin-right: 3.8%;`  Then make another class called "last"  This class is applied to the last div in a "row" and it has `margin-right: 0;` in order to reset the un-needed right-margin of the last div.

Rinse and repeat with the same concept above to make col-1, col-2, col-3, and etc.

Then, you can create any combination you want as long as the classes add up to 12.  So col-6 and col-6 like above, or maybe col-3, col-3, col-3, col-3.  And if you had a reason for it...  col-1, col-2, col-3, col-5, col-1...

Does this help?